# JUnit test case for OSGI bundle

Tags: osgi-bundle

I am trying to write JUnit test case for an external OSGI bundle that I have. 
I tried using Spring DM but then it gave errors while running the test cases - It was not able to start the Spring Extender bundle. Then I found out that the Spring DM is now obsolete.

I want to be able to run a junit test case for OSGI bundles via ant tasks. Any pointers will be of immense help.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do. This is immediately not clear from your question.

If you want to test your code against OSGi service, you may consider a mocking framework such as [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock your services.

If you want to test OSGi bundles developed by you against its OSGi behaviour, you may consider  [Pax Exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Pax+Exam), which can start an OSGi container and run your tests on it.

Let me know if you have any other use case.